Do two vertices sharing the same color in any minimum coloring have a term?
If each color used is one of $k$ given colors, then we refer to the coloring as a $k$-coloring. The smallest number of colors needed to color a graph $G$ is called its chromatic number and is often denoted $\chi (G)$.
In any $\chi (G)$-coloring of a graph $G$, two vertices must be colored the same. Is there a technical term for this?　In other words, is there a term for describing the two vertices that share the same color?
For example, in bipartite graphs with $\chi=2$, vertices in different partitions always have different colors in any 2-coloring.

For example, in bipartite graphs with $\chi = 2$, vertices in different partitions always have different colors in any $2$-coloring. That's true for connected graphs only. In a disconnected graph one may swap colors of all vertices of any component.

Yes. You are right!
